# "Berlin private art school" vs "Private Berlin art school"

Tags: word-order, style, idiomatic-language

I have a sentence which I can change the words in some versions without changing the meaning, but I'm not sure which one is the most natural to the English native speaker, therefore I would like you to give your opinion about which of the options sounds to you more natural?

> Option 1: "Berlin **private** art school"
>
> Option 2: "**Private** Berlin art school"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Order of Adjectives](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order)

1. opinion
2. size
3. physical quality
4. shape
5. age
6. colour
7. origin
8. material
9. type
10. purpose

The order of this list suggests ***Berlin*** (origin) ***private*** (type) ***art*** (purpose) ***school*** would be best.

Keep in mind that this list is not a *rule*, only a general guide.  In some cases you might want to change the order to contrast with another, similar item, for example, a *public* Berlin Art school vs. a *private* Berlin Art school.